# what is the remainder when $7^{2015}$ is divided by $25$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The question says that what is the remainder when $7^{2015}$ is divided by $25$. Please help me out, I am out of ideas (I know that I have to find out the last two digits and I will be done... but I only know how to find the units digit.) and I need your help.

Comment: Suppose you were asked to find the units digit. How would you do it?

Comment: You need to use the same logic when you were finding the last digit.

Comment: Euler function can be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

$7^2\equiv -1\pmod{25}$, so $ 7^4\equiv 1\pmod{25}$, so $7^{2015}\equiv 7^{2015\bmod 4}\equiv 7^3\equiv -7\pmod{25}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$7^2\equiv-1\pmod{25}$$

As $2015=2\cdot1007+1,$

$$7^{2015}=7\cdot(7^2)^{1007}\equiv7\cdot(-1)^{1007}\pmod{25}\equiv-7\equiv-7+25$$

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the last two digits, you need to compute $7^{2015}\pmod{100}$.

According to [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem), if $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod{n}$:

- $\gcd(7,100)=1\implies7^{\phi(100)}\equiv\color\red{7^{40}}\equiv1\pmod{100}\implies$
- $7^{2015}\equiv7^{40\cdot50+15}\equiv(\color\red{7^{40}})^{50}\cdot7^{15}\equiv1^{50}\cdot7^{15}\equiv4747561509943\equiv43\pmod{100}\implies$
- $7^{2015}\bmod{25}=43\bmod{25}=18$

---

But please note that you might as well apply this theorem directly on $25$.

According to [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem), if $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod{n}$:

- $\gcd(7,25)=1\implies7^{\phi(25)}\equiv\color\red{7^{20}}\equiv1\pmod{25}\implies$
- $7^{2015}\equiv7^{20\cdot100+15}\equiv(\color\red{7^{20}})^{100}\cdot7^{15}\equiv1^{100}\cdot7^{15}\equiv4747561509943\equiv43\pmod{25}\implies$
- $7^{2015}\bmod{25}=43\bmod{25}=18$

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be solved using cyclicity.
$7^1=7$
 
$7^2=49$
 
$7^3=343$
$7^4=2401.$
In each last digit is repeating after 4 powers like
$7^5=16807$
 
$7^6=117649$
 
$7^7=823543$
 
$7^8=5764801.$
 The last digits 7,9,3,1 are repeating every 4powers.  So $7^{2015}/25$ what will be remainder. We have to divide 2015 by 4 as cyclicity of 7 is 4. 2015/4 remainder will be 3. In 7’s cyclicity 7^3=343 so we have to divide 343 by 25 and check the remainder. The remainder is 18 hence it is the answer.
Therefore when $7^{2015}$ is divided by $25$ the remainder is $18$. Such an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you found the last digit by looking for a pattern when you do powers of 7 like this:

$7^0=1$

$7^1=7$

$7^2=49\equiv9\pmod{10}$

$7^3\equiv9\times7\equiv63\equiv3\pmod{10}$

$7^4\equiv3\times7\equiv21\equiv1\pmod{10}$

So every 4 powers brings you back to 1. So:

$$7^{2015}=7^{4\times503+3}\equiv7^3\equiv3\pmod{10}$$

You can do the same by looking at the remainder each step when you divide by 25.

$7^0=1$

$7^1=7$

$7^2=49\equiv-1\pmod{25}$

$7^3=-1\times7\equiv-7\pmod{25}$

$7^4\equiv-7\times7\equiv-49\equiv1\pmod{25}$

So it follows the same pattern so it has similar working:

$$7^{2015}=7^{4\times503+3}\equiv7^3\equiv-7\equiv18\pmod{25}$$

Comment: Thanks I figured out the whole approach.

Answer (score 1):

$7$ has order $4$ modulo 25, hence $\;7^{2015}=7^{2015\bmod4}=7^{-1}\mod25$. Now *Bézout's identity*: $\;2\cdot 25-7\cdot 7=1\;$  shows  $7^{-1}\equiv -7\mod 25$.

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi(25)=20$ implies $7^{2015}\equiv 7^{15} \equiv 7\cdot(49)^7 \equiv -7\pmod{25}$.

Comment: Should probably mention that: A. $\gcd(25,7)=1$. B. $2015\bmod{20}=15$. C. $-7\equiv18\pmod{25}$.

Comment: @barakmanos: where did I use $\gcd(25,7)=1$? I just used $49=50-1\equiv -1\pmod{25}$, and $2015\equiv 15\pmod{20}$ is pretty obvious, too.

Comment: But this method wouldn't work if we had (for example) $30$ instead of $7$, would it? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @barakmanos: oh, ok, sure, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the last two digits just like you find the last digit.

{7^0} = 01

{7^1} = 07

{7^2} = 49

(7^3} = ...43

{7^4} = ...01

so that's where the sequence repeats. {7^2015} ends in 43 because 2015 = 4k + 3. So {7^2015} = 18 (modulo 25).

If you were not looking for the remainder modulo 25 (which is easy to see because 25 divides 100), but say 35, you would calculate {7^k} modulo 35 until the values repeat.

For a larger number, say modulo 5100, you'd calculate the values modulo 3, 17, and 100, and combine them.